# Change extension from .ff to .ff.js improve speed?

Tags: javascript, file, asynchronous, xmlhttprequest, browser-cache

Ey! I recently made a small framework to build my small webpages and projects on top.

Today i'm checking a lot of articles about tricks to speed up stuff. I'm interested in improve xhr speed.

I been reading and found some file extensions get usually cached by default and others don't.

I use a filename.ff special extension on my frameworks to known what files i want to fech when accessing a resource.

As a live example
https://bugs.stringmanolo.ga/#projects/fastframework is being downloaded from https://github.com/StringManolo/bugWriteups/blob/master/projects/fastframework/fastframework.ff using XHR when you click the fastframework link in this page https://bugs.stringmanolo.ga/#projects

My question is:
If i change the extension from fastframework.ff to fastframework.ff.js is the file getting cached by the browser and then it will be downloaded faster? Also will be working offline? Or it's already cached? Changing the framework code to use .ff.js isn't going to make a diference at all?

Comment: If you want caching, why not set the Cache-Control headers for the resources you want, instead of relying on functionality that might or might not be there across browsers?

Comment: Because i don't know where the framework is going to run. Works in blogger and site alike. Also i'm using netlify to host my projects.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved it in a better way using service workers and cache api.
I let you the code i used here, so maybe is helpfull to someone in the future.

ff.js (ff is a ff = {} object)

```
/*** Cache Service Workers Code */
ff.cache = {}
ff.cache.resources = [];

ff.cache.start = function(swName, ttl) {
  let tl = 0; 
  tl = localStorage.cacheTTL;
  if (+tl) {
    const now = new Date();
    if (now.getTime() > +localStorage.cacheTTL) {
      localStorage.cacheTTL = 0;
      caches.delete("cachev1").then(function() {
      });
    } 
  } else {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register(swName, {
      scope: './'
    })
    .then(function(reg) {
      caches.open("cachev1")
      .then(function(cache) { 
        cache.addAll(ff.cache.resources)
        .then(function() {
      localStorage.cacheTTL = +(new Date().getTime()) + +ttl;
        });
      });
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
    }); 
  } 
};

ff.cache.clean = function() {
  caches.delete("cachev1").then(function() { 

  });
};
/* End Cache Service Workers Code ***/
```

cache.js (this is the service worker intercepting the requests)

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', (e) => {
 e.respondWith(caches.match(e.request).then((response) => {
  if(response)
   return response
  else
   return fetch(e.request)
 }) )
})
```

main.js (this is the main file included into the index.html file)

```
ff.cache.resources = [
"./logs/dev/historylogs.ff",
"./blogEntries/xss/xss1.ff",
"./blogEntries/xss/w3schoolsxss1.ff",
"./blogEntries/csrf/w3schoolscsrf1.ff",
"./projects/fastframework/fastframework.ff",
"./projects/jex/jex.ff",
"./ff.js",
"./main.js",
"./main.css",
"./index.html",
"./resources/w3schoolspayload.png",
"./resources/w3schoolsxsslanscape.png",
"./resources/w3schoolsxss.png"];
ff.cache.start("./cache.js", 104800000); 
/* 604800000 milliseconds equals 1 week */
```

You can test it live in https://bugs.stringmanolo.ga/index.html is hosted from github repo in case you need to see more code.